# Magento Duplicate Attribute Value

Tags: php, magento, attributes, magento-1.8

I have an attribute "Brands" that i can´t use in layered Navigation, because its part of a plugin that imports external products.

However, i need to use that in filtered Navigation.
What i remember, was to get that value and insert it on Manufacturers attribute, this way i could use it in layered Navigation.

Now, the problem is that i have more than 5000 products, and it would take an eternity to copy the value manually.
I tried to import/export, but the CSV is confusing. and it doesnt even came in rows.

Is it possible to copy the value from Brands to Manufacturers attribute with a php script or something similar?

Comment: this may help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22102367/how-to-copy-a-products-attributes-value-to-another-attribute-in-magento

Comment: HE uses that Observer when attributte is saved, that means i had to open products one by one and save them one by one, for all the products i allready have. That would only work if i was inserting new products